# How to put textblock in container to add background color

Tags: c#, xaml

I am needing to put `TextBlock` inside a container e.g. a Grid In order to put a background color. I know how this works in xaml but in `C# -> (xaml.cs)` a `TextBlock` is made every time the `SaveClose` button is clicked. Therefore one is not originally created.

```
        //In text editing mode.
        if (Notepad.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
        {
            TextBlock block = new TextBlock();
            block.Width = 250;
            block.Height = 100;
            block.Text = Notepad.Text;
            block.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
```

---

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <AppBar>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Name="SaveClose" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}" Content="&#x2714;" AutomationProperties.Name="Save and Close" Click="SaveClose_Click" />
            <Button Name="Delete" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}" Content="&#xE107;" AutomationProperties.Name="Delete Selected" Click="Delete_Click" />
        </StackPanel>    
    </AppBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>

<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.515,0.505">
    <TextBox x:Name="Notepad" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="748" Width="1366" FontSize="30" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    <GridView x:Name="NoteGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="106,350,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="363" Height="168">
        <Button x:Name="NewNote" Content="Create New Note" Height="150" Width="348" FontSize="40" Margin="0" Click="NewNote_Click"/>
    </GridView>
    <GridView x:Name="NoteOutGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="682,84,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="674" Height="590"/>
```

I want every new `textBlock` created to have the same background, how do I go about this?
Thanks

Comment: I suspect that re-creating the textbox is not a cutting edge idea. But anyway you did not show where you put the newly created textbox

Comment: Can you also show your the xaml code? and where the textblock will be located?

Comment: so you just want to set the Background color of the TextBlock?

Comment: I can't add a screen shot but this is a note taking app, and the textblocks are a representation of the notes that the user has saved via clicking a button on the App bar. All the textblocks are created within a Grid ---ps. sorry I'm new hear. bear with me.

Comment: What is the name of the container control that you are wanting to add the TextBlock to

Comment: I was thinking of using a Grid. But I'm not sure how to add the container control in this instance. So its not there and I haven't thought of a name.

Comment: @SandundunEtc I just gave you an example on how to add a textblock to a Grid, see if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I'll try adapt it to mine and see if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case a picture would have helped. I am assuming you are wanting to know how to add your TextBlock to a Grid.

First of all you will need to give your grid a Name so it can be referenced in the CodeBehind. Then simply add your TextBlock to the Grids Children Collection.(I am using a Name of gridName here).

```
gridName.Children.Add(block);
```

if your Grid has rows an columns you will need to use attached properties to Assign your control to the proper location.( I am using rowId and columnId to designate the row and column number of the Grid that the control is being put.

```
Grid.SetColumn(block, columnId);
Grid.SetRow(block, rowId);
```

Putting it together:

**MainWindow.Xaml.cs**

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBlock block = new TextBlock();
            block.Width = 250;
            block.Height = 100;
            block.Text = "Hello World"; // Notepad.Text;
            block.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
            gridName.Children.Add(block);
            Grid.SetColumn(block, 0);  /Not neccesary since not multiple columns
            Grid.SetRow(block, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.Xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
   <Grid Name="gridName" Background="PaleGoldenrod" >
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
           <RowDefinition Height="*" />
       </Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <Button Content="Button" Height="23" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"   Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

Example using UserControl.

**Note.xaml.cs**

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Interaction logic for Note.xaml
   /// </summary>
   public partial class Note : UserControl
   {
       public Note()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }

       public string Text
       {
           get { return block.Text; }
           set { block.Text = value; }
       }

       public new Brush Foreground
       {
           get { return block.Foreground; }
           set { block.Foreground = value; }
       }

       public new Brush Background
       {
           get { return myGrid.Background; }
           set { myGrid.Background = value; }
       }
   }
```

}

**Note.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.Note"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="250">
    <Grid Name="myGrid" >
        <Rectangle Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="4"></Rectangle>
        <TextBlock Name="block" Margin="4"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Modified button click event using new UserControl**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Note block = new Note() { Text = "Hello World", 
                              Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue),
                              Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.PeachPuff),
                              Height=100, Width=250 };
    gridName.Children.Add(block);
    Grid.SetColumn(block, 0);
    Grid.SetRow(block, 0);
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, this is what I was looking for. Adding a background color was the important part. Because the textblock is added to the grid, can I add an object such as a rectangle within that textblock now?

Comment: @SandundunEtc No you will not be able to add a rectangle to the textblock it is control designed to contain a flowdocument. That is why I was asking what the content control was going to be if a Grid you can add multiple objects. Using a Canvas you can position them with Top and Left Attached properties

Comment: I see. If I wanted every created textblock to have a background color as well as a rectangle within it. Would I need a completely different approach?

Comment: @SandundunEtc I may be premature with that statement, I beleive it you put it in a Paragraph or a Run you can do it.

Comment: OK. I'm really sorry but would you be able to explain how I'd use it in this case?

Comment: @SandundunEtc I was right the TextBlock is to lightweight to contain Controls or Shapes. You probably would be better of looking at an UserControl or a RichTextBox.

Comment: I just added an example of an usercontrol with a Rectangle for a border and a TextBlock inside, this sounds like what you are looking for. I will add a couple more properties is a few minutes

Comment: @SandundunEtc just updated the UserControl, play around with it and see if you can get it to work for you.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll tell you how it goes.